# What is the maximum area of the rectangle touching this curve at two points?

Tags: calculus

If $y = 16 - x^2$ and a rectangle is drawn on $x$-axis on an interval of $[-4, 4]$, what is the maximum area of the rectangle?

What I did was substitute with the equation of the curve in $A = xy$ getting $A = 16x - x^3$, $A' = 16 - 3x^2$, $A' = 0$ therefore $16 - 3x^2 = 0$ 
$x = \sqrt(\frac{16}{3})$ substituting in the original curve function we get $y = \frac{32}{3}$ therefore $A = \frac{32}{3} * \sqrt(\frac{16}{3}) = 24.633$

I don't think this answer is correct, if so, what would be the correct answer?

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get multicharacter things under a square root sign, put them in braces, so \sqrt ({\frac {16}3)} gives $\sqrt {(\frac {16}3)}$ and the square root sign extends over all the stuff that should be inside  You did that with the fraction.  It is quite general, subscripts, superscripts, formatting like \text, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You were so so close. In this parabola x is half the width so the area is actually $2x(16-x^2)$

Comment: Well that'd be $32x - 2x^3$ which then becomes $32 - 6x^2$ which still gives off the value $x = \sqrt(\frac{16}{3})$

Comment: It does give you the same value yes, but your area/height will be wrong without that 2

Answer (score 0):

As @The Rod point out you are answer is almost correct. Infact the correct formula is $$A=2xy.$$

This is because $A=xy$ consider only half segment on the base, coming from $0$ to $x$. So you have to consider also the opposite segment starting from $0$ to $-x$. The length of them is exactly $2x$ and this is your basis. The height is given by $y$, thus $A=2xy=32x-2x^3$.

After that you can procede using your method: $A'(x)=32-6x^2$ and $A'(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=\displaystyle\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}$. So the maximum area is 
$$A_{max}=2\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}\Big[16-\Big(\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}\Big)^2\Big]=\frac{2^8\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Comment: I think you intended a denominator of $9$ rather than $3$ in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the maximum of the inscribed rectangle in $f(x)=a^2-x^2$ has a height of $2/3a^2$, which can be easily shown.